# Bokeh Server integration with Bootstrap (front-end component)

Tags: python, web, bootstrap-4, bokeh

In this example, Bootstrap is used for better layout of a Bokeh dashboard.

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/dash

As of Bokeh 1.4.0, is it possible to further integrate Bokeh Server and Bootstrap so that we could trigger callbacks by clicking on Bootstrap components?

An example will be assigning Python (or JavaScript) callbacks to Bootstrap dropdowns (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/) (rather than Bokeh dropdowns). The purpose is mostly cosmetic.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a while ago but I will answer just in case anyone runs across this in the future and is wondering the same things.

The issue with this is that Bokeh, at its core, is a Javascript Package called BokehJS. Bokeh Python libraries are really just a means by which you can interact with BokehJS at a convenient and high level without having to worry about Javascript or Web Development. In the example you posted, the developer is using Bootstrap for styling purposes and creating a more appealing layout by overriding the default bokeh template.

On the other hand, you could develop your own widgets and functionality by extending bokeh using typescript which bokeh provides extensive documentation and examples of [Here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html). Although very time intensive and a lot of work, it can be used to create some nice widgets where you could then integrate bootstrap into a widget and customize its functionality. Otherwise, bootstrap should just be used for styling purposes.